# Class is not getting removed after removeClass JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have a text box as follows:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-regex="Alt. Phone is not correct" 
  data-val-regex-pattern="(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}" 
  id="AltPhone" maxlength="150" name="AltPhone" tabindex="33" type="text"
  value="" class="input-validation-error">
```

I want to remove class="input-validation-error" on tab key and the code for that is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#AltPhone").live('keydown', function (e) {
                var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
                if (code == 9) {
                    $(this).removeClass('input-validation-error');
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }
            });
        });
```

but still I am not able to remove that class from the text box.Here the function being called and also invoking the following line of the code but still that class is appearing at the text box after the function called finished.

```
$(this).removeClass('input-validation-error');
```

Comment: Try this(working example): http://jsfiddle.net/tf0kuxy3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a proper event to manage tab on input, use `blur`

```
$("#AltPhone").on('blur', function (e) {
      //code here
});
```

Comment: No..still the class remains the same der..The thing is that while invoking that line of code  $(this).removeClass('input-validation-error'); the class getting removed but once the function is finished that class again reappears

Comment: oh... so probably the validation plugin is checking for input validity and set the class again. try to empty the input

Comment: You mean after $(this).removeClass('input-validation-error'); I should do $(this).val('');

Answer (score 0):

Use `.keydown()` event instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#AltPhone").keydown(function (e) {
                var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
                if (code == 9) {
                    $(this).removeClass('input-validation-error');
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }
            });
        });
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/j2y9w1x6/

After clicking Tab key, inspect the element in Result section to see that validation class has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because this key intercepts your browser. Try a different key, for example `ENTER`.